# Question for wine and playonlinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux

Today I downloaded the iso of microsoft office 2019 on the pc linux ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I did sudo apt install wine64 and I downloaded wine and then after I downloaded the playonthelinux application always from the terminal.
Ho fatto all the procedure but nothing I can not install office 2019 iso on linux ubuntu asks me for an error in code 0-1018 impossible to install office ?? why how do i properly uninstall the program on ubuntu ?.
Thanks and await answers.

Answer (score 1):

According to WineHQ site, you can't really install MS Office 2019 using wine. The status is "Garbage".

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=37735

Answer (score 0):

You can actually install it and it runs, but with some glitches.

First off, use Wine 5.11 to install it. It will not install with any other version, including newer ones (at least from my experience). Then follow the exact instructions from this page: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=37735

Once installed and confirmed to run, you can then install newer wine versions and it will still run, with some glitches.

Glitches/bugs include:

- Not being able to log into Microsoft accounts (not a problem if it's just for offline use).
- Visual glitches/slowness, such as UI sections turning black momentarily until they are fully created and then appear.
- Some read-only document files that load fine in a Windows-installed version of office won't load into the wine-installed version. You can load them into Softmaker Office/FreeOffice, WPS or LibreOffice and then re-save them as a writable file, and they will load just fine.
- Some UI elements that should be anti-aliased aren't.
- It does not exit cleanly, leaving a bunch of zombie exe processes running. You have to end/kill them manually after you're done using Office.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow both the [setup of @MikeF](https://askubuntu.com/a/1283349/62883) (Wine) and the version discussed [here for PlayOnLinux](https://technowikis.com/5838/how-to-install-microsoft-office-2019-on-linux) (which of course uses Wine as well). I also 'merged' these two versions by using a PlayOnLinux with Wine 5.11 specified. But to no avail.

At first everything goes fine, although there is some weird symbol before and after text.
[image: Installer starts with minor issues]

The main issue is that the installer turns black the moment that the installation starts. Then it gets stuck at 59% (they might or might not be related issues). [image: Black installer gets stuck at 59%]

I've tried to play around with various graphics options and libraries, but that didn't help. In all cases I was left with the [following log](https://serverlenn.myds.me:45001/d/s/632105415271824540/J8JLaiUFn4GVWB5SMTKFFqHAA_1sdx9M-wbzAdIqwxQg_) (although small issues existed because me trying with intel and nvidia graphics and with and without msxml6/riched20).

Comment: I've tried 4.01, 4.0-RC1 installation got stuck at 57%. 5.11 stuck at 59%. 5.15 throws error 30088-45 at 59% or 65%, 6.01 installation throws an error at 100% If i install components dx9, dx10, dx11, urlmon, msxml6, riched20 in a 5.15 wine it goes up to 97% (error 30015-11)